# Notepad++ replacing a series of characters with numbers

Tags: notepad++

I have a document in which I have to replace some special characters with numbers in ascending order.
I have marked those characters as "&&", I have to replace first 14 && with 1, next 14 && with 2, next 14 && with 3 and so on....next 14 && with 250.
Is there a better and fast way to do it. 
Thanks..

Comment: Have you taught about using a language like c++ to read in the file using the <ifstream> libary altering the data and then writing the data back to a file ?

Comment: Yes but I could only think... I don't know any C++.

Comment: What language are you comfortable with ?? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of accomplishing your task in Notepad++, is with the use of Python Script plugin.

1. Install Python Script plugin, from Plugin Manager or from the [official website](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/).
2. Then go to Plugins > Python Script > New Script. Choose a filename for your new file (eg replace_series.py) and copy the code that follows.
3. Run Plugins > Python Script > Scripts > replace_series.py and a new tab will show up the desired result.

```py
number = 1
content = editor.getText()
while "&&" in content:
    content = content.replace("&&", str(number), 14)
    number += 1

notepad.new()
editor.addText(content)
```

Comment: Then in the above code change `&&` to `[0]` and `content.replace("&&", str(number), 14)` to `content.replace("[0]", "[" + str(number) + "]", 14)`.

Comment: I tried this and it failed to achieve what I wanted... the problem is the 3rd argument to .replace should be 1, meaning one substitution, then advance the while loop.  Otherwise as coded it will do 14 substitutions with the same value of number.  In my case, finding that the argument was optional and the default is all, I removed it.  I got all my replaces done with the same value.  Using 1 forces the loop to increment the number.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this in java,
it's not very nice, but it should work

```
private void readAndWrite() {
    String [] lines = new String[1000];
    try {
        int n=0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:/test.txt"));


        while (br.readLine()!=null) {
            lines[n]=br.readLine();
            n++;                
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("d:/test2.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        int num =1;
        int count=1;
        String test="";
        int p=0;
        while (lines[p]!= null) {
             bw.write( lines[p].replace("&&", Integer.toString(num))+"\n");
             bw.newLine();
             bw.flush();
            count++;
            p++;
            if (count==15) {
                count=1;
                num++;
            }

        }
        fw.close();


    }catch (NullPointerException e) {

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```