# Create a list of image paths based on file image names

Tags: notepad++

I need to create a list of file images:

```
Custom Text for image1: NovTheSenses001.jpg
Custom Text for image2: NovTheSenses002.jpg
```

...
until

```
Custom Text for image100: NovTheSenses100.jpg
```

After, I need to create the following list of image path based on the previous list:

```
<img class="aligncenter" alt="Custom Text for image1" src="http://www.mysite.com/images/NovTheSenses.001.jpg" width="360" height="360" />
<img class="aligncenter" alt="Custom Text for image2" src="http://www.mysite.com/images/NovTheSenses.002.jpg" width="360" height="360" />
```

etc...

In this case 'alt' variable content will be replaced by the custom text of the list 'Custom Text for image1' and 'src' variable content will be replaced by 'http://www.mysite.com/NovTheSenses001.jpg' until 'http://www.mysite.com/NovTheSenses100.jpg'.

How can I achieve that using Notepad++?

Many thanks.

Comment: try yourself ...where you get the problems then come up with your error...

Comment: MUST it be Notepad++? I think Excel would be better suited for a quick job like this.

Comment: This is something simple for someone who knows how to use Notepad++ with the search/replace function, I have no idea what to put in the search field so it can get the two variables and replace them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to create a new list of files without having something specific to replace, you will most likely need to create a script to do this. The only way I can think of accomplishing this in Notepad++, is with the use of Python Script plugin.

1. Install Python Script plugin, from Plugin Manager or from the official website.
2. Then go to Plugins > Python Script > New Script.
   Choose a filename for your new file (eg imgFileList.py) and copy the code that follows.
3. Run Plugins > Python Script > Scripts > imgFileList.py and a new tab will show up the desired result.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

   import string

   count = 100
   list1, list2 = [], []

   while count > 0:
       imgNum = 99-count
       list1.append("Custom Text for image%i: NovTheSenses%s.jpg"%(imgNum, string.zfill(imgNum,3)))
       list2.append('<img class="aligncenter" alt="Custom Text for image%i src="http://www.mysite.com/images/NovTheSenses.%s.jpg" width="360" height="360" />"'%(imgNum, string.zfill(imgNum,3)))
       count -= 1

   final1 = "\n".join(list1)
   final2 = "\n".join(list2)

   notepad.new()
   editor.addText(final1)
   editor.addText(final2)
   ```

If you are looking for a way to do a fancy replacement to an existing list, you can also refer to this answer:

[Notepad++ replacing a series of characters with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197122/notepad-replacing-a-series-of-characters-with-numbers)

Hope this helps. :)